# Iterating through dozens of Excel Sheets while summing up a specific cell or similiar stuff?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have dozens of Excel files named very similar. For instance:

"I_XXX_YY_ZZZ Surname, Name" the only constant is the I, it doesn't ever change. Every single one of these excel file is made according to a template. So the cells inside them do no vary, they are all the same.

From these files I need the following:

- a) What number is written in cell J40?
- b) What is the sum in cells G20:G40?
- c) If 2014 in A10:A20, then sum every cell from B10:B20 where 2014 is present in A.

What I can do is create a Masterfile.xlsx, put all the I_ names in cell, and put the a) b) c) next to the names via something like this I_XXX_YY_ZZZ Surname, Name!J40, etc.

But I really don't fancy doing it this way. I'd like some sort of iteration or something to that effect.

Here's an example how the Masterfile.xlsx will look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nzNa.png

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I haven't a clue if Excel is even capable of perfoming this task. What I can do is create a new excel file called Masterfile.xlsx, and put all the Excel file names in a cell, and then the a) b) c) via "I_XXX_YY_ZZZ Surname, Name **!J40**", etc. into cells next to the names. But that's incredible tedious, so my question was if there's a way to simplfy this task through some sort of iteration or something.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. But nobody will write the script for you.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Be nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: I didn't ask for a complete script. I can do it myself, what I rather need to know if excel can do it, and if so, how?

Comment: Googling "excel vba processing many files" returns [Code for looping through all excel files in a specified folder, and pulling data from specific cells](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5851531) as the second result. By the way I don't even use Excel or VBA ...

Comment: Well, see, here's the problem: I didn't think abou vba and excel because I rarely if ever use vba in excel, which is why I asked this question in the first place. I wouldn't come up with this, so I didn't google it.

Comment: Well now you know. If it looks hard to do in Excel think about a VBA solution ;)

Comment: Are all the files in a single folder??

Comment: Yes. All the files in a single folder. The Masterfile.xlsx might be in another folder, or in the same folder. Preferably in another, but if it's easier to do in the same folder, so be it.

Comment: There's no way that I know of to pull values from closed files using just formulas. You could use VBA or you could get fancy and used an Excel 4 macro in a named range but Excel will still see that as a macro and you'd have to save it as a macro-enabled file. The VBA option is probably better because it'd be easier to follow / debug and you could have it run an update and store static values instead of a bunch of formulas to a UDF which would take a long time to recalculate.

Comment: Thanks. VBA it is then. Now I need to find a way to realize my idea. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Is it not possible to change [I_2013_10_001_Surname-Name.xlsx]CSneu'!$C$4 to something like [[A2].xlsxCSneu'!$C$4, because I have all the file name in A2:A100 besides that, nothing changes.

Comment: Have you considered using the INDIRECT() function to build the references according to variables in other cells? That's the way I'd typically consider to solve similar problems without VBA.